# NSFetchResults update delegate works first time, crashes second time

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've looked around SO for similar answers, but my issue seems a litte different.

I have a UITableView that is tied to a NSFetchResultsController. The goal is to pull up some data, add a couple rows into the Context, and the table is automatically updated. Simple, right?
init -> empty table -> performFetch -> create some objects in the Context -> delegate sees this and updates my table.

I'm using the boilerplate NSFetchResultsController for noticing when the current context has been modified.

When I run this with a clean Simulator/iOS platform, the NSFetchController successfully recognizes that data in the Context has been updated. But if I run the app a second time, I get the following error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change
processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of 
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: 
index 40 beyond bounds for empty array with userInfo (null)
```

The crash occurs on calling [self.tableView beginUpdates];

In my debugging I can see that '[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]' is completely empty and I think thats the problem - shouldn't this be updating with my test data since I modified the context? I'm using the Apple Recipe and CoreDataBooks examples as reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because you Data Modle in class just not fit the entity in you .xcdatamodeld file.